# ping works but ssh fails

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ip

1. machine1 IP: 172.30.11.119
2. machine2 IP: 172.30.11.120
3. machine3 IP: 172.30.11.121
4. machine4 IP: 172.30.11.122

> Note: 
>          These machines are connected to LAN.

I have configured the static IP for Ethernet interface of each machine as in above in /etc/network/interfaces file in order to persist the IP even after system reboot.

I have set the default gateway as 172.30.11.97 in machine 4 (in order to reach it from user desktop via putty connection manager)

```
allow-hotplug eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
      address 172.30.11.122
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 172.30.11.97
```

But in other 3 machines I didn't set the default gateway as done for 122. Instead I tried policy routing in those 3 machines like below in the "interfaces" and "rt_table" file:

```
 echo "1 policy_gw" >> /etc/iproute/rt_table
    In /etc/iproute/rt_table:
      1 policy_gw
```

In /etc/network/interfaces:

```
      allow-hotplug eth0
      iface eth0 inet static
              address 172.30.11.121
              netmask 255.255.255.0

      post-up ip rule add dev eth0 table policy_gw
      post-up ip route add default via 172.30.11.97 dev etho src 172.30.11.121/24 table policy_gw
```

Done like that for 120/119 machines. Now I can reach these machines directly via putty.

**Problem faced**: I am able to ping every machine in this LAN from some other machine in the same LAN. But ssh is failing with the error `port 22: no route to host`

Suppose if I am in machine 121 : ssh 172.30.11.120 is throwing the above error.

> default gateway is a cisco system router/switch.They are blocking
>   ports for SSH,telnet protocols but not ICMP.

**Routing table of machine 122**:

```
root@debian:~# route -n                                       
Kernel IP routing table 
Destination  Gateway      Genmask       Flags   Metric Ref Use Iface 
0.0.0.0      172.30.11.97 0.0.0.0       UG       0      0   0  eth1 
172.30.11.0  0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0 U        0      0   0  eth1
```

**Contents of ssh_config file**:

```
Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

Comment: What does this mean ? `They are blocking ports for SSH,telnet protocols but not ICMP.`

Comment: Well there is nothing you can do, I don't think you can run SSH through ICMP, so you will need a port unblocked.

Comment: Does your server have ipv6 enabled? (If it were a firewall issue, you shouldn't get "no route to host".)

Comment: @lain : The machine IP configured with default gway IP 172.30.11.97 is a cisco switch/router . It has the port for SSH,telnet closed and ICMP port open.

Comment: can you add the ssh command you are using ?

Comment: @kranteg : ssh 172.30.11.120 trying from 121/119/122

Comment: Can you update your question with the route table of the 122 for example ? And your ssh_config file from 122 ?

Comment: Are these machines connected with a physical switch? If so, is it the same switch as the gateway?

Comment: routing table of 122:root@debian:~# route -n Kernel IP routing table Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface 0.0.0.0 172.30.11.97 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 eth1 172.30.11.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 eth1

Comment: @David Houde: These machines are connected to physical Lan switch. This inturn connected to the router which serves as the default gw machine.

Comment: I don't get this sentence: _set the default gateway as 172.30.11.97 in machine4(in order to reach it from user desktop via putty connection manager)_

Comment: Talk to the administrator of the router/switch.

Comment: Have you tried nmapping these nodes (assuming you're allowed to)? Are you sure ssh is running on those nodes?

Comment: You can use another for (non filtered) port fot SSH.

Comment: in your ./ssh folder, do you have a config file? (you could define different hosts here, that ping do not have access to). this could explain the difference between ping and ssh. also try direct connection  (not via the switch).

Answer (score -1):

Does you hosts located in the same physical network?

"no route to host" - it seems to be an icmp answer from your router, your can test it with network analyzer. It seems your ssh traffic goes via router, despite hosts are located in the same network, maybe your policy_gw table have higher priority, than builtin table local. Router refuses to forward it (but in the same time it allows icmp somehow) or it really have no route to destination. See your router's tables or correct your policy routing for your hosts talk directly, as they should.